# Angular router - Get Target-URL of current navigation process

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an NG-module with nested routing.

- Main.module with main.component
- Sub.module with sub.component

Pathes look like this: *http://domain/mainroute/nestedroute*

Now, in the **sub.component** i want to make a decision for rerouting based on the target-URL that was provided (by user or external redirect). So if a user targets a nested route directly, I want to check if i let him pass or if i redirect him to a different location.
For that, i need to find out the URL that was typed in when initializing the **sub.component**.

However, in the `sub.component`:

```
constructer(private router: Router){
    console.log(this.router.url)
}
```

the log returns http://domain/mainroute even though http://domain/mainroute/nestedroute was typed in and gets directed to.
This might be because the navigation process runs the constructor of sub.component before doing further routing.

now the question is: how can i access the full route at this point?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent entering to route under specified circumstances I suggest using [angular guards](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards). It's router based mechanism designed for such needs.

If the problem is just getting target url address I'm afraid this data is not available in angular router, but you can use `window.location.href`